# Redirecting ip/folder to url

Tags: apache, web, centos, ip, redirect

I'm trying to redirect web application that was initially set on some xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/folder/ address.

after the I'v set a url for the site (www.example.com) I made VirtualHost to redirect everything from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/folder/ to www.example.com

but my site still send to users mail with links for the old address 
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/folder/some_link and because of the VirtualHost the links break.

I can't change the links that my site generates. but I want to redirect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/folder/some_links to www.example.com/some_links.

I'v tried all kinds of options but nothing seems to work.
I use apache webserver on centosOS.
thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you actually ask... Obviously URL rewriting cannot magically change the links you send out in your emails, that is up to you. URL rewriting only handles _incoming_ requests.

Comment: you'll need to contrast how what you want to change differs from what you say you already changed in the second sentence of the question.